# JQuery crashes after 105 letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a weird one to me. I'm currently creating a multiple choice quiz using js/jquery, and I've found that if I enter a question that is greater than 105 characters in length, the script just doesn't run & no buttons can be clicked.

For example, using the code I've provided this will run absolutely fine and I can have a multiple choice quiz working fine. However, changing the question to a different that is over 105 characters breaks it.

For example, if I changed

> "Multiple choice q1"

to

> "The process ‘PopularScreenSavers.exe’ is running in the background of a user's laptop. What could this be an example of? " (a question I want to include)

essentially stops my script from running at all.

Included below is the current js as well as a snippet of the relevant html body. It all works perfectly fine... except when I want a longer question.

Any help would be appreciated.

### CODE

```js
(function() {
  const myQuestions = [
    {
      question: "The process ‘PopularScreenSavers.exe’ is running in the background of a user's laptop. What could this be an example of? ",
      answers:
      {
        a: "a",
        b: "b",
        c: "c",
        d: "d"
      },
      correctAnswer: "a"
    },
    {
    question: "Multiple choice q1",
    answers:
    {
      a: "",
      b: "",
      c: "",
      d: ""
    }
  
}];

  function buildQuiz()
  {
    const output = [];
    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) =>
    {
      const answers = [];
      for (letter in currentQuestion.answers)
      {
        answers.push(`<label>
           <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
            ${letter} :
            ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
         </label>`);
      }
      output.push(`<div class="slide">
         <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
         <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
       </div>`);
    });
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
  }

  function showResults()
  {
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll(".answers");
    let numCorrect = 0;
    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) =>
    {
      const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
      const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
      const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) ||
      {}).value;
      if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer)
      {
        numCorrect++;
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "#009A44";
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.fontWeight = "900";
      }
      else
      {
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "#DA291C";
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.fontWeight = "900";
      }
    });
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
  }

  function showSlide(n)
  {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active-slide");
    slides[n].classList.add("active-slide");
    currentSlide = n;
    if (currentSlide === 0)
    {
      previousButton.style.display = "none";
    }
    else
    {
      previousButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1)
    {
      nextButton.style.display = "none";
      submitButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    else
    {
      nextButton.style.display = "inline-block";
      submitButton.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  function showNextSlide()
  {
    showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  }

  function showPreviousSlide()
  {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }
  const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
  const resultsContainer = document.getElementById("results");
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
  buildQuiz();
  const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
  const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  let currentSlide = 0;
  showSlide(0);
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
})();
```

```html
<head>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="quiz-container">
  <div id="quiz"></div>
</div>
<button id="previous">Previous Question</button>
<button id="next">Next Question</button>
<button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Edit: adding that this runs as valid js, but it doesn't run in Chrome - should have specified, apologies.

#### jsfiddle

These fiddles should show the issues I'm having:

Working - https://jsfiddle.net/3m5afcuo/

Not working (only change made was to the string) - https://jsfiddle.net/su3hptdq/

Comment: jsfiddle or demo ?

Comment: your myQuestions doesn't look right - looks to be some missing brackets

Comment: The code is working you are missing brackets,comma ...etc debug properly.

Comment: @Pete yeah, that was me being stupid and misreading my own code... the original issue still persists though!

Comment: @SumeshTG that was just a transposition error. the original issue (string > 105 characters causes a problem) is still an issue

Comment: adding a real test case to the snippet with a question with more than 105 chars, no problems occured, as you can see running your own snippet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mv65dr7c/ Is this not what you want?

Comment: @nyep Could you regenerate that issue in your question itself?

Comment: the provided jsFiddles are the same

Comment: @CalvinNunes fixed, thanks

Comment: @SumeshTG should be more obvious now, added in a jsfiddle to demo

Comment: your problem have nothing to do with jQuery... it's just CSS, `div.slide active-slide` is getting bigger because of the length, so it is over the button, letting it not clickable...

Comment: @nyep It is css issue. Try to use bootstrap for UI.

Comment: well, adding a z-index and a margin to the button in jsFiddle, I made it work...

Comment: @CalvinNunes how would i fix this?

Comment: rebuild your html structure (use more divs as containers) and use CSS to move elements to right places

Comment: @CalvinNunes thanks. if you add this an answer, i will mark as solved